# Creating a manual backup. Are applications and virtual directories supported?

Tags: iis-7, msdeploy

Let's say I have created the following in IIS:
1. A website called 'MyMusicBlog'.
2. Added an application 'Umbraco'.
3. Added a virtual directory called 'services'.
4. Added an application 'RssService' below the services.
5. Added an application 'RestService' below the services.

so the following url's are available:

- http://www.mymusicblog.com/umbraco
- http://www.mymusicblog.com/services/rssservice
- http://www.mymusicblog.com/services/restservice

Now when I want to manually create a backup using the 'backupManager' provider in msdeploy.exe I see that the deployment package that is created does not contain the content for the application 'Umbraco' and services 'RssService' and 'RestService'.

What I tried:

```
msdeploy.exe -verb:sync -source:backupManager -dest:backupManager=MyMusicBlog
```

What Elliott Hamai says about it:
http://www.iis.net/learn/publish/using-web-deploy/web-deploy-automatic-backups

I wonder whether Web Deploy supports the scenario where you want to manually create and restore a backup for an IIS application.

Who has tried to do this and succeeded? Or did you find a workaround?

It seems to me that I can create a deployment package and 'restore' the content if needed. In that way you use a deployment package as a 'backup' package. But ideally you would expect Web Deploy to support manual backups for these kind of sites.